# How to link branch template children items (data sources) with its parent renderings in Sitecore 7.2?

Tags: datasource, branch, processor

I'm following this blog post from Zachary which is pretty clear.

http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/march/30/using-sitecores-new-addfromtemplate-item-provider-pipeline

The only issue is that the proposed processor uses `AddFromTemplateProcessor` as the base class.

I'm doing this work for a **Sitecore 7.2** instance and it looks like the above-mentioned class isn't on `Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider` from `Sitecore.Kernel.DLL` as usual.

What is the strategy to achieve this goal in a Sitecore 7.2?

Answer (score 0):

After a long investigation, it looks like this is **not possible at all** in Sitecore 7.2.

After reading [this article](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/investigating-the-pipeline-based-item-provider-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) from John West I realized that the concept of **pipeline-based item provider** was introduced on Sitecore 8 only.

So even if I still can use the `<uiAddFromTemplate>` pipeline, which does the work when using the `Insert from template` option, there is no way I can use the `<addFromTemplate>` pipeline to make the solution more complete.

Comment: But you can still use Alen Pelin's SmartCommands

Comment: He is using <event name="item:added"> with a custom handler... Interesting. I'll take a look at his solution Mark, thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that these commands were originally designed to deal with Item Clones only. But I've been using an adapted set of them for years and years, to solve the Branch Template issue. You'd need to fork the repo.